# Integral of the product of two error functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to know whether this integral could be solved analytically

$ \int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{a-\text{x}}{k}\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{L+2
   \text{x}}{2 k}\right) \, d\text{x} $

where $\text{erf}(\cdot)$ is the error function, k and L are constants, and $a\in[-L/2,L/2]$.

Edit: I think this integral can be written in the form

$ \int_{u}^{v} \text{erf}\left(\frac{z-\text{x}}{k}\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{z+
   \text{x}}{k}\right) \, d\text{x} $

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of error function and changing the order of integration?

Comment: Yes, I also tried with Mathematica without success. (it seems that Mathematica is not very efficient in evaluating integrals involving erf, even when the analytical solution is known to exist)

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do. Meanwhile, $k$ has no meaning here, you can get rid of it easily